# Как сайт получает видео с вебкамеры?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, httpwebrequest

Есть сайт на котором можно смотреть видео с камер города, а точнее [одна](http://m-live.tv/wcameras/cam10_720p/#) из его страниц (камера №10, но на сайте называется №17).

Я в принципе понимаю, что сайт делает запрос `ip:.../cam10_720p.m3v8?e=...&st=...` и на основе этого списка делает запрос на само видео `ip:.../cam10_720p.ts`.

Но так как я не веб-программист, я не могу разобраться, как формируются параметры `e` и `st` у первого запроса. Прошу помочь.

Comment: Не как, это статичная ссылка со статичными данными, находится в HTML странице.

Comment: Вон даже для подтверждения этого накатал [такой](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rCViPy) простенький пример, который берет объект `<source>` из html и у него получает ссылку. Для наглядности взял камеру на главной странице, а также 1-5-ю, ну и страницу "контакты", где видео нет. Как видим ссылки все успешно отдались без каких либо лишних манипуляций, открыл их через простой плеер и успешно увидел те самые видео с камер. Так что вы походу изобретаете велосипед.